# Error on installing IPython for Python 3: sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"

Tags: python, python-3.x, ipython, opensuse

I want to install IPython for Python3 using

`sudo pip install ipython`

on openSUSE 13.1. Since I have pip only installed for Python3 it should work and in fact works for other packages. I get the follwoing error:

```
Downloading/unpacking ipython
  Downloading ipython-4.1.2.tar.gz (5.0MB): 5.0MB downloaded
  Running setup.py egg_info for package ipython
    error in ipython setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    error in ipython setup command: Invalid environment marker: sys_platform == "darwin" and platform_python_implementation == "CPython"
```

Interestingly, IPython works, but starts with Python 2.7.6 after installation via YaST. What is going wrong?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is likely due to an out-of-date setuptools. Try:

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools pip
pip list
pip install ipython
```

(with sudo, if necessary)

Comment: Had this problem after upgrading to python27 via SCL on centos6. This solution worked like a charm!